# How can I align text to the left of my image that is centered?

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

This is what I have so far for the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!--meta tags -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <title>name of website</title>
</head>
<body>
  </div>
         <div class="topnav">
         <img src="../images/website logo-01.png" width="80" height="80" alt="logo" class="logo">
                        <header>
              <nav>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
                      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                     <li> <a href="target="_blank">Resume</a>
                    </ul>
            </nav>

<header id="portrait">
  <img src="../images/portrait.jpg" width="2000" height="2000" alt="portrait" class="portrait"
  style="float: left; margin-right: -8000px; margin-bottom:">

  <p>this is where the text wold be going</p>

  </header>

        <main>
          <main>
            <aside>

<div>
        </main>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy4nL.jpg)

I would like the text to be aligned where the yellow bordered box is, and would appreciate some help.

Comment: It would be better if you could please share CSS file too or use jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css flex property like, put the image and text inside a div and add use display:flex property to the div and then you can use can use the order property if you want image and text in different order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by putting your `<img>` and your `<p>` tag together inside one div and by using display:flex on that div element.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `p` tag before the `img` and do as follows:

**HTML**

```
<header id="portrait">
   <p>this is where the text wold be going</p>
   <img src="../images/portrait.jpg" alt="portrait" class="portrait">
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
#portraid {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
   align-items:center;
   justify-content:center;
}
```